# How to save each column of a data frame into separate sheets in one excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below pandas dataframe:

```
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Krish', 'John'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

How can I save each column as a separate sheet in one excel file. So, the excel file would consist of two sheets. I am looking for a general code which can be applied to other dataframes with many number of columns as well. I assume a for loop can resolve this issue.

Comment: And what have you tried so far to get this done?

Comment: for i in range(1):
    z=df.iloc[:,i:i+1]
    f=z.copy()
    with pd.ExcelWriter("new_df.xlsx") as writer:
        z.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="column"+str(i))
        f.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="column"+str(i))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Krish', 'John'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer: 
    for col in df.columns: 
        df[col].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=col, index=False)
```

`df.columns is a list of column names` 
`sheet_name = column name`